# some confusion in box topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $x_1,x_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of points of the product space $\prod X_\alpha$. Show that the sequence converges to the point $x$ if and only if the sequence $\pi_\alpha (x_1), \pi_\alpha (x_2)\ldots$ converges to $\pi_\alpha (x)$ for each $\alpha$. Is this fact true for box topology instead of product topology?

i found the answer  here,,,,As i could not able to understand the red lines...[image]

Pliz help me ...

Comment: for $a_i$ to converge to $a$, you must prove that for every neighbourhood of $a$, there is a $n$ such that for all $a_i$ whose index $i$ is greater than $i$ (that is all $a_i$ after the $n$ first), all those $a_i$ are in the neighbour hood.  With the product topology, you can select the maximum $n$ in the projected spaces because there are finitely many of those that are non-zero, and pull it back to prove convergence in the product space.  With the box topology, there might be an infinity of such $n$ in the projection spaces, with no maximum values to pull back to the product space.

Comment: @Lærne how can show that   there might be an infinity of such n in the projection spaces???? im not getting

Comment: "might be" -> find a example.  For instance consider the $\alpha$'s are indexed in $\mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$, each $X_\alpha$ is $\mathbb R$ and $x_i$ is $(1/i, 1/i, 1/i, \dots)$.  Now consider the box neigbourhood $\prod_{i \in \mathbb N  \setminus \{0\}} (-1/i,1/i)$.  Then $n = 2$ in $X_1$, $n = 3$ in $X_2$, $n=4$ in $X_3$, ...

Answer (score 1):

i have 3 answer..

$1)$Consider the product of $\Bbb N$ copies of $\{0,1\}$ (with the discrete topology). The result is the Cantor space. This is a compact metric space, and therefore it has a countable basis, and only $2^{\aleph_0}$ open sets.

Consider the box topology on the same product, then you get a discrete space of size $2^{\aleph_0}$, which therefore has $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ open sets, and is most certainly not compact.

$2)$Now let us consider the sequence the sequence $\mathbf{x}_n \colon= \left( \frac{1}{n } , \frac{ 1 }{ n }, \frac{ 1 }{ n }, \ldots \right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. For each $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, we note that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to the point $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. However, $\mathbf{x}_n$ does not converge to the point $\mathbf{x} \colon= ( 0, 0, 0, \ldots )$ if $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is given the box topology, for the set 
$$ U \colon= \left( - \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4} \right) \times \left( - \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{9} \right) \times \left( - \frac{1}{ 16 }, \frac{1}{ 16  } \right) \times \cdots $$ is a box topology open set in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, and so if $\mathbf{x}_n$ belongs to $U$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then for that $n$, we would also have $\pi_n \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right) \in \pi_n (U)$, that is, 
$$ \frac{1}{n} \in \left( \frac{1}{ (n+1)^2 }, \frac{1}{ (n+1)^2 } \right), $$
which is not true.

$3)$This is not true if we use the box topology instead of the product topology. Consider the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, the countably infinite cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself. Let $$x_n = \left( \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \frac{3}{n}, \ldots \right)$$

Clearly, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\pi_k(x_n) \longrightarrow 0$. However, it is not the case that $x \longrightarrow \textbf{0}$. To see this, consider the basis element $U = \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^\infty (-1, 1)}$ containing $\textbf{0}$. Then, for all $x_n$, $x_n \notin U$, since we can always find a $k$ such that $\pi_k(x_n) > 1$.